# How do you enable Actionbar folder affordances like new GMail app

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to create an Android application that uses the same ActionBar folder affordances that the new GMail application employs (the Three horizontal lines to the right of the GMail M).
and when pressed a folder menu list slides out from the right side of the screen

i have tried searching the google docs but have failed to find what i am looking for.
I had guess it was a slidingDrawer widget, however that has been deprecated in API 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three lines to the LEFT of the icon slide out the new Navigation Drawer pattern which was introduced by google at this years Google I/O.

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 5):

It's called a [DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) and is part of the official support library. The Android training section provides a good tutorial on it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

[Here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#side-nav) you can find an in-depth design documentation of how you should use it and how its navigation should work.

Comment: Ahmad thanks for pointing out the DrawerLayout, however what i had in mind is the Navigation Drawer (with The "Hamburger" icon in the actionbar)